# The conservation of a critical non-linear dispersion equation.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Consider the non-linear problem

> $$ \frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}-\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\sigma|u|^{\lambda-1}u$$
>   $$u(x.0)=f(x)$$

Suppose that $u$ is a smooth solution that decays sufficiently quickly as $|x| \to \infty$.Here $\sigma$ is a non-zero real number and the exponent $\lambda$ is greater than 1. Show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u|^2dx$ is independent of $t$.

What I did:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\int u\bar{u}dx=\int(\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}\bar{u}+u\frac{\partial{\bar{u}}}{\partial{t}})dx=i\int(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial{x}^2}\bar{u}+\sigma|u|^{\lambda+1}+\frac{\partial^2{\bar{u}}}{\partial{x}^2}u+\sigma|u|^{\lambda+1})dx$$
By integration by parts, 
$$ \int(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial{x}^2}\bar{u}+\sigma|u|^{\lambda+1}+\frac{\partial^2{\bar{u}}}{\partial{x}^2}u+\sigma|u|^{\lambda+1})dx=\int\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{x}^2}(u+\bar{u})+2\sigma|u|^{\lambda+1}dx$$
I don't understand that I don't solve it beacause it seems to easy. I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you missed a minus sign when taking the conjugate of your equation, everything is multiplied by $-i$, so you should be subtracting in your second equality.

Comment: You must have the sharp eyes! Thanks.